# No Class Defined Error In J2Me

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish, kxml2

I developed an app in j2me which is working fine in default emulator. I added 3rd party library in this app but I'm facing a problem when I try to deploy it in device(Mobiles) . I get an error of `Undefined Exception.` Please help me to solve it.

Comment: It looks like your libraries are not bundled with your code. How do you create your jar file?

Comment: i am using netbeans it automaticaly creates jar... i find problem is one class document builder factory is not found..although i hadd added KXML jar....when i realize i change every thing to json and it works

Comment: Did you solve the issue using only json?

Comment: yes i had added json jar file and convert all ksoap method to json